# Java boolean issue

Tags: java, boolean

```
private static final Pattern namePattern = 
    Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,12}");

if (player.getName().length() < 3 || 
        player.getName().length() > 12 || 
        namePattern.matcher(player.getName()).matches()) {
    player.ban("[Autoban] Character-name PE", true);
    return;
}
```

The code is kinda obvious, I hope

If the players name is longer than 12 or shorter then 3, or have any symbols that shouldnt be i a name = BAM, ban!

but even thought my player name is like Chaos or test, it gets autobanned by this code.
idk if the namepattern  Pattern blocks characters aswell, I just it to block symbols like `"!#&%¤/&%(/)(/(=)$@£$@£{€@£` yeh...
What am I doing wrong :(?

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant `(!namePattern.matcher(player.getName()).matches())`.

Also, you could've use only the regex match: `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,12}` since it checks for length.

**Edit:**

You can use such a function

```
public void banIfNeeded(Player player)
{
    Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,12}");
    if(!namePattern.matcher(player.getName()).matches()) {
        System.out.print("Banned"); 
        // Ban somehow
    }
}
```

As @bkail commented (thanks!), there's no need for the `^` and `\z` so I removed them :)

Comment: Thanks it works now but even if my char is named something with !"__#!"_#! or a symbol like that, it doesnt get banned. only lenght check seems to work.

Comment: Anchors ("^" and "\z") are unnecessary when using .matches().

Comment: How can I check if the player use a symbool in the name then? i want to block all symbols

Comment: How can I check if the player use a symbool in the name then? i want to block all symbols

Comment: I just gave you an example. just use `player.getName()` instead of `s`.

Comment: public void nameCheck()
{
    Pattern name1Pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,12}");
    String s =  " !\"__#!\"_#!";
    if(!name1Pattern.matcher(s).matches()) {
        System.out.println("Banned");
        banip("[Autoban] Character-name PE", true, true);
        return;
 }
}

I did like that and the function bans me even if the player name is Rawr or test.

Comment: It doesn't. receive the string to check as an input, I just gave an example.

Comment: Shouldnt it ONLY return banned if the characters is illegal or shorter than 3 or longer than 12? ...

Comment: You took my example, but didn't make it generic, I showed you that the regex is enough, but I will edit the answer so it would be clearer.

Comment: I now saw ur new "banIfNeeded" function but does that check for symbols aswell? !"#&&)(/=) and so on..

Comment: Yes. it allows only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ or -